# Incorrect LastBoot time of Remotehost

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

The Uptime script showing correct LastReboot time on LocalHost however showing incorrect LastReboot time of RemoteHost. LocalHost converting the RemoteHost time into LocalTime

```
Function get-Uptime {
Param([string]$computername=$env:computername)
Process{
if ($_) {$computername=$_}
    $Computerobj = "" | select ComputerName, Uptime, LastReboot
    $WOS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
    $LastBootUpTime = $WOS.ConvertToDateTime($WOS.LastBootUpTime)
    $Uptime = (Get-Date) - $LastBootUpTime
    $day =$Uptime.Days
    $hour =$Uptime.Hours
    $minute =$Uptime.Minutes
    $second = $Uptime.Seconds
$Computerobj.ComputerName = $computername
$Computerobj.Uptime = "$day Days $hour Hours $minute Min $second Sec"
$Computerobj.LastReboot = $LastBootUpTime
$Computerobj    
}
}

*****LocalHost****** LastReboot Correctly displayed***

ComputerName : LocalHost
Uptime       : 72 Days 12 Hours 56 Min 14 Sec
LastReboot   : 1/29/2014 3:18:46 AM
TimeZone     : (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)

*****RemoteHost****** LastReboot incorrectly displayed***

ComputerName : RemoteHost
Uptime       : 73 Days 12 Hours 47 Min 52 Sec
LastReboot   : 1/28/2014 3:27:55 AM

*****Actual/Correct LastReboot time on RemoteHost******

ComputerName : RemoteHost
Uptime       : 73 Days 12 Hours 47 Min 52 Sec
LastReboot   : 1/28/2014 12:27:55 AM
```

Note sure how I can use DATETIME to obtain the correct LastReboot time of RemoteHost

```
$DateTime = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LocalTime -ComputerName $computername

$DateTime_STR = Get-Date -Year $DateTime.Year -Month $DateTime.Month -Day $DateTime.Day -Hour $DateTime.Hour -Minute $DateTime.Minute -Second $DateTime.Second
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the reboot time in the remote server's localtime, but `ConvertToDateTime()` gives you your local system's localtime. You can work around that issue by converting the time to UTC and adding the remote server's timezone offset:

```
$server = '...'

$os = gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $server

$localtime     = $os.ConvertToDateTime($os.LastBootUpTime)
$universaltime = $localtime.ToUniversalTime()
$remotetime    = $universaltime.AddMinutes($os.CurrentTimeZone)
```

Comment: Getting following error "Unable to find type [TimeZoneInfo]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded."

Comment: The `TimeZoneInfo` class is provided by .Net framework 3.5 or newer. Try `$localtime.ToUniversalTime()` instead.